# How can we show that parallel transport is invertible?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, inverse-function

We have that the map $\Pi^{pq}_{\gamma}: T_pS \rightarrow T_qS$ that takes $v_0 \in T_pS$ to $v_1 \in T_qS$ is called parallel transport from $p$ to $q$ along $\gamma$.

$\Pi^{pq}_{\gamma}: T_pS \rightarrow T_qS$ is a linear map and an isometry.

How can we show that the parallel transport map $\Pi^{pq}_{\gamma}: T_pS \rightarrow T_qS$ is invertible?

$$$$

---

$$$$

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inverse is given by parallel transport along the inverse path.

Let $\gamma : [0, 1] \to S$, with $\gamma(0) = p$ and $\gamma(1) = q$. If $v_0 \in T_pS$ and $X$ is a vector field on the image of $\gamma$ such that $X_p = v_0$ and $\nabla_{\gamma'}X = 0$, then we set $\Pi^{pq}_{\gamma}(v_0) = X_q$ (which you called $v_1$).

Now let $\hat{\gamma}(t) = \gamma(1-t)$, so $\hat{\gamma} : [0, 1] \to S$, $\hat{\gamma}(0) = \gamma(1) = q$ and $\hat{\gamma}(1) = \gamma(0) = p$. Note that $\hat{\gamma}' = -\gamma'$ so if $X$ is the vector field above, $\nabla_{\hat{\gamma}'}X = \nabla_{-\gamma'}X = -\nabla_{\gamma'}X = 0$ and $X_q = v_1$, so $\Pi^{qp}_{\hat{\gamma}}(v_1) = X_p = v_0$.

Note, the same argument works for parallel transport on any vector bundle with connection. The only thing that changes is that $X$ is replaced by a section of the bundle which is covariantly constant along $\gamma$.

Comment: $X_p$ is the value of the vector field $X$ at the point $p$, right? The vector field $X$ is parallel along to $\gamma$, right?

Comment: Why does it stand that $$\nabla_{\gamma'}X = 0$$ and not $$\nabla_{\gamma}X = 0$$ ?

Comment: $X_p \in T_pS$ is the value of the vector field at $p$ and the condition $\nabla_{\gamma'}X = 0$ is precisely what it means for $X$ to be parallel along $\gamma$. Note that $\nabla_{\gamma}X$ is not defined as $\gamma$ is not a vector field.

Comment: I added a part of the book at my initial post... Could you take a look at it? Do you not mean the notation of the Definition 7.4.2?

Comment: That notation is not the standard one. A connection $\nabla$ on a vector bundle $E$ is a map $\nabla : \Gamma(TX)\times\Gamma(E) \to \Gamma(E)$, $(X, \sigma) \mapsto \nabla_X\sigma$ satisfying certain properties. In particular, the subscript is always a vector field.

Comment: Even still, the same proof should show that parallel transport is invertible.

Comment: Ok... Using the notation of the book we have the following: $$$$ $\gamma$ and $\hat{\gamma}$ are different parametrizations of the same curve and the tangent space on a point of a curve doesn't depend on the parametrization. We have $X\in T_{\gamma(t)}S$, so $X\in T_{\hat{\gamma}(t)}S$. So $X$ is a tangent vector field parallel along $\hat{\gamma}$, right? $$$$ If $v_1\in T_qS$ and $X$ the above tangent vector field such that $X_q=v_1$, then do we set $\Pi^{qp}_{\hat{\gamma}}(v_1) = X_p = v_0$ ? Or how do we get to that formula?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34336/discussion-between-michael-albanese-and-mary-star).