# Why is the backwards curve needed for the inverse of a parallel transport?

Tags: differential-geometry, connections

Dearh math.stackeschange-community,

I'm at a loss with the following problem:

Let $I=(a,b)$, then the inverse of the parallel transport $P_{s,t}^\gamma$ from $s \in I$ to $t \in I$ along the curve $\gamma: I \rightarrow M$, then its inverse is given by the transport $P_{t,s}^\delta$ from $t$ to $s$ along the "backwards" curve $\delta: I \rightarrow M, \delta(r) = \gamma(a+b-r)$ for all $r \in I$.

I've seen this proven in several books and I'm also aware of  [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1610032/how-can-we-show-that-parallel-transport-is-invertible), so I'm convinced that it is correct.  However, why is the inverse not simply given by $P_{t,s}^\gamma$, i.e. by the transport from t to s along the *same* curve?

To be honest, this seems like a stupid question - shouldn't those two things intuitively be exactly the same thing? I can imagine three different outcomes: Both approaches indeed define the same parallel transport, the second transport it somehow non-sensical and can't be defined or the second one is simply not the correct inverse.

However, here is my proof that $P_{t,s}^\gamma P_{s,t}^\gamma = Id$:

Let $X_0 \in T_{\gamma(s)}M$, then $P_{s,t}(X_0) = X(t)$, where $X: I \rightarrow TM$ is the unique vector field along $\gamma$ (i.e. $X(r) \in T_{\gamma(r)}M $ holds for all $r \in I$) with

$$D_t X (r):= \nabla_{\dot{\gamma}(r)} X = 0$$

for all $r \in I$, and

$$X(s) = X_0.$$

Now, since X fulfills those properties, it is also the unique vector field used in the second parallel transport. It follows that

$$P_{t,s}^\gamma P_{s,t}^\gamma(X_0) = P_{t,s}^\gamma(X(t)) = X(s) = X_0$$

which was the claim.

I'd be very thankful for any comments, explanations or hints!

Comment: Your "backward" curve is not OK as stated; it should read "$\delta(r) = \gamma(a + b - r)$". Now, it's not true that $\dot{\delta}(r) = \dot{\gamma}(r)$; instead, the chain rule gives $\dot{\delta}(r) = -\dot{\gamma}(a + b - r)$. That means you have to do a tiny bit of adjustment to calculate the backward parallel transport along $\gamma$ (a.k.a., the parallel transport along $\delta$). The end result confirms your intuition (as far as I understand your intuition), however.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I fixed the typo. However, I think you missed the point of my question. I was not trying to prove that the transport along $\delta$ is the inverse (in which case I had to address the issue you mentioned) but I was proving that the transport along the _same_ curve $\gamma$ also yields the inverse.

Comment: If $\gamma:[a, b] \to M$ is a piecewise-$C^{1}$ path, then parallel transport along $\gamma$ maps $T_{\gamma(a)}M$ to $T_{\gamma(b)}M$. Consequently, parallel transport along "the same curve" (i.e., along $\gamma$) cannot possibly be its own inverse, because the domain and target spaces are wrong. If you prefer, I think there's a semantic issue: A _path_ is a _mapping_, not a set of points. The paths $\gamma$ and $\delta$ are _different paths_, but in a sense they're "the same curve" because they trace the same set of points of $M$. [...]

Comment: Thus, when you speak of "parallel transport backward along the same path", it's technically a contradiction in terms. That geometric idea, however, is precisely what is meant by "parallel transport along the backward path $\delta$."

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replies! I think we're getting a lot closer to my exact misunderstanding. However, I still have an issue:

Comment: If I have a curve $\gamma: I \rightarrow M$, then according to "Riemannian Manifolds: An Introduction" (Lee) the parallel transport operator $P_{s,t}$ maps $T_{\gamma(s)}$ to $T_{\gamma(t)}$ for arbitrary $s,t \in I$. There is no mention of $s,t$ having to be the endpoints of $I$ or even $s<t$. However, my guess would be that general values from $I$ that are not the endpoints are allowed because you can easily restrict the curve to that interval. But this only works if they are in the correct order, so $s<t$ has to be supposed for the above formula to be accurate. Is that true?

Comment: Yes regarding restriction, and I believe it's standard to assume $s < t$. :) (Jack Lee participates at this site, so there's a reasonable chance you'll get definitive clarification from the author himself.)